# How to add and substract 15 minutes from date sql

Tags: mysql, date, dateadd

I have a query to search records depending on latitude longitude and the date.

The query works fine for the same date, but I want to get records which are 15 minutes before the date and 15 minutes after the date.

Working query is this:

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM post 
WHERE st_lati LIKE '19.878454%' AND st_longi LIKE '73.836708%' 
AND ed_lati LIKE '20.012709%' AND ed_longi LIKE '73.791389%' 
AND pt_date LIKE '2017-05-30 06:30%'
```

I tried to minus 15 minutes using dateadd function but its giving errors.

my attempt

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM post 
WHERE pt_date DATEADD(minute, -15 * @h - @m, pt_date) 
AND st_lati LIKE '19.878454%' 
AND st_longi LIKE '73.836708%' 
AND ed_lati LIKE '20.012709%' 
AND ed_longi LIKE '73.791389%'
```

I want to get records where pt_date before 15 minutes and after 15 minutes.

Comment: 1. If you get errors, then you _quote them verbatim_ in your question. 2. You are missing a comparison operator here, `WHERE pt_date DATEADD(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM post 
WHERE st_lati LIKE '19.878454%' 
  AND st_longi LIKE '73.836708%' 
  AND ed_lati LIKE '20.012709%' 
  AND ed_longi LIKE '73.791389%' 
  AND pt_date BETWEEN '2017-05-30 06:30:00' - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE AND 
  '2017-05-30 06:30:00' + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
```

Comment: $params = array("$st_lati%", "$st_longi%", "$ed_lati%", "$ed_longi%", $pt_date); I am getting bound parameters error for this, number of parameters dose not match. @ReneS

Comment: Yes, you would need to pass `pt_date` twice as it's used twice now in the query

Comment: if the time is 6:30 i am not getting records of 6:18,6:15,6:55 not working fine

Answer (score 0):

I use the [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function for this sort of thing, where you have the dates in ISO format, or close to it.  This allows you to work in seconds (so 15 minutes is 60 * 15):

The relevant part of your `where` clause should be:

`AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(pt_date) BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-05-30 06:30')-60*15 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-05-30 06:30')+60*15;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use difference in minutes. Query will be like this:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM post 
WHERE st_lati LIKE '19.878454%' 
  AND st_longi LIKE '73.836708%' 
  AND ed_lati LIKE '20.012709%' 
  AND ed_longi LIKE '73.791389%' 
  AND ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, pt_date, '2017-05-30 06:30')) <= 15;
```

Comment: I need records 15 minutes after the date too.

Comment: In that case, you can use ABS() function.

Comment: if the time is 6:30 i am not getting records of 6:18,6:15,6:55 not working fine

Comment: Disadvantage of this method is that an index on `pt_date` cannot be used